# Ctrl+Click para abrir uma classe Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Ao tentar abrir uma classe, seja do meu próprio projeto ou nativa do Java usando o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Clique, a seguinte mensagem aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu configuro o Eclipse para abrir o código fonte da classe usando o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Clique?

Já vi pessoas tendo que utilizar um plugin instalado pelo Marketplace e configurando nas preferências do Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você esteja utilizando Maven ou alguma outra ferramenta de gerenciamento de dependência, e a dependência possuir um `source` atrelado ela irá ser mostrada automaticamente.

No caso de dependências sem `source`, você pode utilizar a seguinte extensão do Eclipse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A classe irá ser aberta da mesma forma de hoje:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o botão direito você pode abrir com um decompilador instalado pela extensão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E pronto!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]